# value of a variable from other php file changes completely if different option is selected?

Tags: php, variables

I was writing a small php program in which I have to perform addition on a variable taken from other php file.

For example 
First File :  score1.php

```
    <?php
        $result =0;
    ?>
```

Second File: score2.php

```
    <?php
        include_once 'score1.php';
        $result1 = 1;
        $option = $_GET["input"];
            if($option == "yes")
                $result1 = $result1 + $result;
            else
                $result1 = $result;

    ?>
```

Third File: score3.php

```
    <?php
        include_once 'score2.php';
        $result2 = 5;
        $option2 = $_GET["input"];
            if ($option2 == "yes")
                $result2 = $result2 + $result1;
            else
                $result2 = $result1;
    ?>
```

Now if I select option yes everytime, then there is no problem. But when I select option other than yes, the result value reverts back to 0.My goal is to keep the value of result from previous file to another file which is including it. Any solution ?

Comment: Follow your logic flow from the top to the bottom of this post, going to the else clauses each time - zero is exactly what would be expected here. What do you want it to be instead?

Comment: I want the previous value saved when traverse from one file to another.

Comment: Variables in PHP also do not persist between page requests. (Which your code hints at being intended.)

Comment: use `session_start()` store result in `$_SESSION['result']`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's totally normal. In fact, in `score2.php`, if you fall in the else condition `$result1` will have the value of `$result`, which is ... 0 !
Then, in `score3.php`, as php is stateless, it will load `score2.php` and `$_GET['input']` is not set, which means it will fall in the else condition.. AND boom, again `$result1` will get the value of `$result` (=> 0).

By the way, what is your goal ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP scripts in different files "don't know of each other". You're only `including` them without the logic being performed when you called them before. So script3.php does not know what happened when you called sript2.php and will alwas use the default value after you `include_once 'score2.php';` (which is $result1 = $result in the else part).

You need to start a session or communicate previous results via GET parameters.